# Why is NotImplementedType not a type subclass?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I noticed something strange when inspecting the built-in type `NotImplementedType`.

```
>>> from types import NotImplementedType
>>> issubclass(NotImplementedType, type)
False
>>> type(NotImplementedType)
<type 'type'>
```

How can these two things be true? How can `NotImplementedType` not be a subclass of `type` but yet be derived from `type`?

Comment: By using `type(..)` on a `type(..)` you obtain the *meta-type*, and the meta-type of `NotImplementedType` is indeed `type` (most types have meta-type `type`). But that does not mean that the class itself is a subclass of type.

Comment: Not sure why this totally legitimate question is getting downvoted

Answer (score 4):

Classes are not a subclass of `type`, including `types.NotImplementedType`. `type` is the *metaclass* of classes.

For example, custom classes and built-in types are not subclasses of `type` *either*:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> issubclass(Foo, type)
False
>>> issubclass(int, type)
False
```

Only other metaclasses are subclasses of `type`; like the `ABCMeta` metaclass:

```
>>> from abc import ABCMeta
>>> issubclass(ABCMeta, type)
True
```

This is analogous to intances and classes; instances are not subclasses of their class; use `isinstance()`:

```
>>> issubclass(Foo(), Foo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
>>> isinstance(Foo(), Foo)
True
>>> import types
>>> isinstance(types.NotImplementedType, type)
True
```